# Кабель-Переходник

Tags: usb, sd

Как сделать кабель-переходник с Micro SD на Mini USB! 
Будет подключон вместо флешки внешний HDD!

Comment: У меня есть цыфровой фотоапарат на него входит 16 Гб...это мало для меня!!! Мне нужно подключить к неме внешний жосткий диск!!! Результат?!

Comment: Смею заметить, жёсткие диски с микроСД мало схожи)

Comment: По значению что это и то - есть память. Разница, грубо говоря, в размере носителя.

Comment: Нет, вы абсолютно не правы) Разница там офигительная в интерфейсах.
Если вы хотите подключать жёсткий диск как microsd, то делать там надо то же самое, что я и написал, только наоборот. Плюс реализовать обработку всех команд протокола и корректный на них ответ) Но не факт, если вы и сумеете сделать, что фотоаппарат ваш сумеет с большим объёмом памяти совладать. Проще купить вторую карту, чем заниматься извращенствами с диском, который при таком режиме легко угробить)

Comment: В чем и прикол мне нужна беспрерывная съемка на некотором промежутке времени. Приблизительно 18-36 часов беспрерывной съемки!

Answer (score 1):

Ну, собственно, *просто кабель* сделать *не получится*. Т.к. для работы SD вам понадобится контроллер... И еще контроллер USB... И т.д.  Т.е. это будет уже не кабель-переходник, а кард ридер. Дешевле купить готовый кард ридер для микроСД...

Answer (score 0):

Дешевле купить китайский.

Но если вас интересует самопал, то берёте arm7/arm9 со встроенным usb2.0, смотрите пример с реализацией mass storage device, пишете или берёте готовую библиотеку для SD-карт (от того же elm-chan, или EFSL).

Ну и добавляете взаимодействие между ними. Но на скорость не рассчитываете)

Comment: А по конкретней?! Ссылку или что...

Comment: Первый попавшийся из гугля: http://microsin.ru/content/view/678/44/

Comment: Немного непонятно по вашей ссылке!

Comment: Вы не сможете собрать - закажите какому-нибудь мастеру по контроллерам и радиоэлектронике либо поищите готовую. Дел там не так и много, но требуют наличия кучи специфических знаний.

Comment: Ну а сами бы вы взялись за такую работу? И сколько бы это стояло?